# How to know whether a particular preprocessor directive is defined in a third party DLL or not?

Tags: visual-studio, c++, dll

I'm using a definition from a DLL. There are multiple definitions in the DLL and one will be picked based on conditional preprocessor macro declaration. How to know which preprocessor declaration is used in the DLL?

Comment: What do you mean by "definition from a DLL"?.. this is FAR to ambiguous.  If we are talking about DLL exports.. that's easy.. if we are talking about #define X 10 vs #define X 11.. it becomes far more difficult.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor directives and macros exist only at compile-time. Except possibly in debugging information, a compiled binary, such as a DLL, does not generally contain any information about preprocessor directives or macros.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies.
If the source file of the DLL being used is as follows:

file1

> #ifdef x
>          struct A { 
>                  int a; 
>                  float b; 
>          };
>
> ## else
>
> ```
>    struct A { 
>            int a; 
>    };
> ```
>
> ## endif

In the user code struct A is being instantiated. Is there any way where we can know which struct definition from the DLL is being used? There is no source and other information available from DLL provider on how the DLL is built.

Comment: Please don't publish your reply as an answer. Instead you can make a comment of edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the problem statement but if you want decompiler there are few choices like ILSpy, DotPeek and others.